# check if two values of lists have the same numbers return how many are same

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am trying to check if two parameters of lists have the same numbers and if so how many of them are same. I would like to use a for loop to do this.

so far I have tried this but it doesn't work.

`num_1 = get_how_many_match(2, [5, 2, 2, 5, 2]) 
    num_2 = get_how_many_match(5, [5, 2, 2, 5, 2]) 
    num_3 = get_how_many_match(4, [5, 2, 2, 5, 2]) 
    num_4 = get_how_many_match(3, [5, 3, 4, 3, 3]) 
    num_5 = get_how_many_match(6, [5, 2, 2, 6, 2])`

```
def get_how_many_match(value_to_match, list_of_dice):
list = [0]

for num in list_of_dice:
    if value_to_match in list_of_dice:
        value_to_match == num
        a = len(str(num))
        list = num

return list
```

The output I get is:

```
2 2 [0] 3 2
```

But the output I want is:

```
3 2 0 3 1
```

Because in num_1, the number 2 occurs three times and so on...

Comment: You forgot to include crucial information: *How* doesn't the code work? Did you get output? If so, how did it differ from what you *expected*? Or was there an error? If so, include the full traceback. But do tell us what you expected the output to be still.

Comment: There are a couple of things: You cannot name a variable list because list is the name of a python structure. In the if statement you should write if value_to_match == num: since you iterate through the list

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried this yet it still doesn't seem to work. I have edited my question . Please see if you can figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `get_how_many_match` is completely incorrect. Consider this which produces the desired results:

```
>>> def get_how_many_match(value_to_match, list_of_dice):
...     return list_of_dice.count(value_to_match)
... 
>>> num_1 = get_how_many_match(2, [5, 2, 2, 5, 2]) 
>>> num_2 = get_how_many_match(5, [5, 2, 2, 5, 2]) 
>>> num_3 = get_how_many_match(4, [5, 2, 2, 5, 2]) 
>>> num_4 = get_how_many_match(3, [5, 3, 4, 3, 3]) 
>>> num_5 = get_how_many_match(6, [5, 2, 2, 6, 2])
>>> 
>>> print num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5
3 2 0 3 1
```

If that is so, then perhaps:

```
def get_how_many_match(value_to_match, list_of_dice):
    count = 0
    for dice in list_of_dice:
        if dice == value_to_match:
           count += 1
    return count
```

Would meet the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am not allowed to change or add things to the get_how_many_match (), I need to use loop to cheack if the number exists in the list and if so how many numbers are there.

Comment: I did it a different way but using the list_of_dice.count (value_to_match) , but it really helped thank you